# Android application with actionbar tabs and listview/gridview below

Tags: android, layout, menu, tabs, android-actionbar

Hi im trying to do simple applicatnion (media player). I got some questions. I already done a menu with 3 buttons (in menu.xml file), 3 tabs done in MainActivity.java. And my question is: 
how to make that items (buttons, and tabs) applied to all Activities? Do i need to paste code from MainActivity everywhere? (addTab, override functions etc) in my opinion there must be other way. What is more: i would like to do that when ill click tab1, the listview apears below, if i click tab2, the gridview apears below. Should i do 3 diffrent layouts and 3 diffrent activities for my 3 tabs? or 1 layout and 1 activity with all items ? How it should looks like.

I already done that when i click a tab1 i start new activity, onCreate function of that new activity loads new layout with listview (for tab2 gridview) but in this case im missing my actionbar and tabs :( when i copied actionbar and tabs code from MainActivity application dont even start :( however what i said before, it would be strange if i would be forced to paste that code everywhere

My menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_home"
      android:icon="@drawable/navigation_back"
      android:title="@string/action_home"
      android:showAsAction="always" />"
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="always" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM =        "selected_navigation_item";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section_music)
        .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section_video)
        .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section_photo)
        .setTabListener(this));
}
  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current tab position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
      getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current tab position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
        .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
  }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            //openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            //openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerListViewActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(intent);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
  }

/*
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            String[] tekst = {"Music", "Video", "Settings", "Exit"};
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + tekst[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(position == 3)
            {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to write the code again extend you second activity to Mainactivity instead of activity.

Public class SecondActivity extends Mainactivity
simple :)
hope it helps you

Comment: epic advice man! works almost perfectly. please take a look on my override onTabSelected function. how to check which tab is selected? what is more i got some bug, when i put code from onTabSelected to onOptionsItemSelected case action_home for example - it works PERFECTLY, however when that code stay on onTabSelected app crashes, maybe becouse of that on start app 1st tab is always selected, maybe becouse im running it on AVD not real device. idk rly

Comment: tab.getposition() you will find that method
@Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

  int i = tab.getPosition();
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

Comment: Please dont extend it to Main activty as i said 
metion your applicatiob bar theme in mainfest in application tag
create a dummactivty write all actionbar methods in that and extend every activty to dummy activity